# Firebase Cloud Functions: Import Environment Configurations from File?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

According to [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env), environment configs can be set by running the command:

```
firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

However, I am wondering is there a way to import environment configs from a file e.g. from a JSON file `configs.json`:

```
firebase functions:config:set configs.json
```

Comment: There is not.  You could write your own program to read the json and convert that into a series of firebase CLI commands that get the job done.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Doug! :)

Comment: tthanks ...  I tried .  firebase functions:config:set service_account="$(cat service-account.json)" . and I get all parameters ...  checked with firebase functions:config:get service_key    so it's definitely an answer ...   answer it and I'll vote ...

Comment: forgot to menton that in order to testv locally ...with firebase serve , then I MUST run before .  firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json ...  as unctions.config() is only available within the Cloud Functions runtime