# How to make two json file configurations for different Firebase projects?

Tags: json, firebase, configuration, google-cloud-functions

We have two Firebase project, one for developing another production project. We use cloud functions. In one cloud functions, you need to use service-account-credentials.json. The problem is how can I make this function take data from service-account-credentials-dev.json when it proceeds to the development project, and when on production, then from service-account-credentials-prod.json?

I know about the environment, but as I understand, this feature does not allow you to download the json file for a particular project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45098388/firebase-cloud-functions-import-environment-configurations-from-file). Doug Stevenson wrote "There is not. You could write your own program to read the json and convert that into a series of firebase CLI commands that get the job done"